# Take $ n^\text{th} $ sub-list with equal distances

Tags: list-manipulation

I have been looking at `Span`, `Take`, etc. functions but I couldn't figure out how can I extract elements likes this

```
A = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, l, m, n, o, p}
```

And I want this : `A' = {b, c, f, g, l, m}`.

Basically, I am looking at the elements with a distance of 4 + their next elements:
`{b, f, l}` + their associated next elements `{c, g, m}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Flatten @ Partition[Rest @ A, 2, 4]
```

> {b, c, f, g, l, m}

or

```
A[[Flatten @ Partition[Range[2, Length @ A], 2, 4]]]
```

> {b, c, f, g, l, m}

Also

```
Table[Sequence @@ A[[{i + 1, i + 2}]], {i, 1 , Length[A] - 2, 4}]
```

> {b, c, f, g, l, m}

Answer (score 4):

This returns the 2nd and 3rd elements from successive 4-element chunks, and is directly generalizable to any chunk size or element selection:

```
Flatten@Map[{#[[2]], #[[3]]} &, Partition[A, 4]]
```

> {b, c, f, g, l, m}

Same as above, using shorthand for Map:

```
Flatten[{#[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ Partition[A, 4]]
```

> {b, c, f, g, l, m}

This gives the first letter of the pair at the end without its mate, so to eliminate it you'd need to drop the last letter:

```
Riffle[Downsample[A, 4, 2], Downsample[A, 4, 3]]
Drop[Riffle[Downsample[A, 4, 2], Downsample[A, 4, 3]],-1]
```

> {b, c, f, g, l, m, p}
>
> {b, c, f, g, l, m}

Similarly:

```
Drop[{Downsample[A, 4, 2], Downsample[A, 4, 3]}~Flatten~{2, 1}, -1]
```

> {b, c, f, g, l, m}

Answer (score 2):

```
Riffle[A[[2 ;; ;; 4]], A[[3 ;; ;; 4]]];
```

or

```
Flatten[Transpose[{A[[2 ;; ;; 4]], A[[3 ;; ;; 4]]}]]
```

The latter is easily generalizable to more than two "spans".

Also notable:

```
Flatten[Partition[A, 4][[All, 2 ;; 3]]]
```

For unpacked list `A`, the method with `Riffle` seems to be the best among these (on my machine). For packed integer list `A`, second method seems to be a bit faster.

Comment: To the downvoter: Is something not right with this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this simpler one:

```
 Flatten[Table[{A[[i]], A[[i+1]]},{i,2,Length[A]-1,4}]]
```

`Flatten` is used to remove curly brackets.